# how to fetch data from multiple many to many relationship table using single query

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I have this table scenario in my database. I want to fetch data from all these tables in single query using form name and it is unique. I dont know how many other data related to formNumber. I tried using FolloWing query but i didnt get result.

```
select [FormNumber], [FormName], [ProcedureName] ,[MethodName], [DeptName], [SectionName]
            FROM FormDetail AS fd INNER JOIN FormMaster AS fp ON fd.[FormId] = fp.[FormId]
            INNER JOIN FProcedure AS fpr ON fp.[ProcId] = fpr.[ProcId]   
            INNER JOIN FMethod AS fm ON fp.[MethodId] = fm.[MethodId]
            INNER JOIN FDepartment AS fdp ON fp.[DeptId] = fdp.[DeptId]
            INNER JOIN FSection AS fs ON fp.[SecId] = fs.[SecId]
            WHERE [FormNumber] = '1026 -3'
```

I got following result
[image]

It returns with proper result but it repeats data with all other record. E.G if there is two department and twelve section then it will first fill first department with 12 section and then again fill second with all section. I Want that it doesn't repeat that E.g If there is only two department it fetches only two and 12 section only twelve no repeatation with another data.

Comment: Use distinct as in "select distinct..."

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i have used that but it did not work

Comment: Do I understand it right that the all many-to-many relationships are stored on FormMaster? If so how does that table look like, structure and data?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Form Master Table Contains all tables Primary key as a foreign key if there is data for one table and not for others only one will fill and rest of others are null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your keeping all many-to-many mappings in one table I believe you need to do a subquery for each mapping. In my example below I only have three tables, with similar names, but the query is easily expandable by adding sub-queries and also adding a condition for the sub-query id and the form id. I also use distinct to avoid duplicates.

```
SELECT distinct number, mq.name AS method_name, pq.name AS proc_name
FROM form f, master m,
(SELECT m.fid as id, name FROM master m JOIN proc p ON m.pid = p.id) AS pq,
(SELECT m.fid as id, name FROM master m join method me ON m.mid = me.id) AS mq
WHERE m.fid = f.id
  AND pq.id = f.id
  AND mq.id = f.id
```